# Unable to create URI with whitespace in MarkLogic

Tags: python, rest, marklogic

I have created a Marklogic transform which tries to convert some URL encoded characters: [ ] and whitespace when ingesting data into database. This is the xquery code:

```
xquery version "1.0-ml";

module namespace space = "http://marklogic.com/rest-api/transform/space-to-space";

declare function space:transform(
    $context    as map:map,
    $params     as map:map,
    $content    as document-node()
  ) as document-node()
{

    let $puts := (
        xdmp:log($params),
        xdmp:log($context),
        map:put($context, "uri", fn:replace(map:get($context, "uri"), "%5B+", "[")),
        map:put($context, "uri", fn:replace(map:get($context, "uri"), "%5D+", "]")),
        map:put($context, "uri", fn:replace(map:get($context, "uri"), "%20+", " ")),
        xdmp:log($context)
    )
    
    return $content
    
};
```

When I tried this with my python code below

```
def upload_document(self, inputContent, uri, fileType, database, collection):
        if fileType == 'XML':
            headers = {'Content-type': 'application/xml'}
            fileBytes = str.encode(inputContent)
        elif fileType == 'TXT':
            headers = {'Content-type': 'text/*'}
            fileBytes = str.encode(inputContent)
        else:
            headers = {'Content-type': 'application/octet-stream'}
            fileBytes = inputContent

        endpoint = ML_DOCUMENTS_ENDPOINT
        params = {}

        if uri is not None:
            encodedUri = urllib.parse.quote(uri)
            endpoint = endpoint + "?uri=" + encodedUri

        if database is not None:
            params['database'] = database

        if collection is not None:
            params['collection'] = collection

        params['transform'] = 'space-to-space'

        req = PreparedRequest()
        req.prepare_url(endpoint, params)

        response = requests.put(req.url, data=fileBytes, headers=headers, auth=HTTPDigestAuth(ML_USER_NAME, ML_PASSWORD))
        print('upload_document result: ' + str(response.status_code))

        if response.status_code == 400:
            print(response.text)
```

The following lines are from the xquery logging:

1. 2023-02-13 16:59:00.067 Info: {}
2. 2023-02-13 16:59:00.067 Info:
   {"input-type":"application/octet-stream",
   "uri":"/Judgment/26856/supportingfiles/[TEST] 57_image1.PNG", "output-type":"application/octet-stream"}
3. 2023-02-13 16:59:00.067 Info:
   {"input-type":"application/octet-stream",
   "uri":"/Judgment/26856/supportingfiles/[TEST] 57_image1.PNG", "output type":"application/octet-stream"}
4. 2023-02-13 16:59:00.653 Info: Status 500: REST-INVALIDPARAM: (err:FOER0000)
   Invalid parameter: invalid uri:
   /Judgment/26856/supportingfiles/[TEST] 57_image1.PNG

Comment: Spaces and square brackets are all allowed in URIs for MarkLogic (see https://help.marklogic.com/knowledgebase/article/View/valid-characters-in-a-marklogic-document-uri). Inserting your URI via query console works.  I also believe that the message is misleading - "invalid uri" is not about URI format, but the error due to various other issues.  If you are sure that you are using the document PUT endpoint correctly, then I would open a  bug with MarkLogic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The MarkLogic REST API is very opinionated about what a valid URI is, and it doesn't allow you to insert documents that have spaces in the URI. If you have an existing URI with a space in it, the REST API will retrieve or update it for you. However, it won't allow you to create a new document with such a URI.

If you need to create documents with spaces in the URI, then you will need to use lower-level APIs. `xdmp:document-insert()` will let you.

Comment: Upvote for the answer.. Still.. Strange that the REST API would throw errors on URI format that is different from what the database allows.

Answer (score 0):

The lower level APIs have allowed it, but the newer REST API tightened this up.

See https://help.marklogic.com/knowledgebase/article/View/valid-characters-in-a-marklogic-document-uri